# Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (Drupal + PHPexcel)

Tags: php, drupal, phpexcel

```
    <?php
    function import_sales_request(){

    $hostname = '****';
    $username = '****';
    $password = '*****';

    global $base_url;

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
    $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN', SE_UID);
    $emailDates = array();

    if ($emails) {
    //$count = 1;
    rsort($emails);

    foreach ($emails as $email_number) {

    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, FT_UID);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2, FT_UID);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number, FT_UID);


    $emailDates[$email_number] = $overview[0]->date;

    $message_header = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $email_number, 1);
    $message_body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.1", FT_UID);

    //file_put_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . "/mail/" . $email_number . ".htm", nl2br($message_header) . $message_body);

    $attachments = array();
    if (isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {
            $attachments[$i] = array('is_attachment' => false, 'filename' => '', 'name' => '', 'attachment' => '');
            if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach ($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach ($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i + 1, FT_UID);
                if ($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                } elseif ($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        if ($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1) {
            $filename = $attachment['name'];
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
            if (in_array($fileinfo['extension'], array('csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'))) {
                if (empty($filename))
                    $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                if (empty($filename))
                    $filename = time() . ".dat";
                $fp = fopen(drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . "/mail/".$email_number."-".clean($overview[0]->from). "-" . clean($filename), "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
    //if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
    imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);
    }
    }
    imap_close($inbox);
    import_sales_request_into_database($emailDates);
    return true;

    }


    /*
    * Insert new and revised request into database
    */

    function import_sales_request_into_database($emailDates = '', $flag = false) {

    global $user;
    global $base_url;
    include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . '/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
    $filelist = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . '/mail', '/^.*\.(csv|CSV|xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX)$/');
    if (!empty($filelist)) {

    foreach ($filelist as $list) {

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($list->uri);
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    $resultArray = array();
    $part_no = array();
    $start_part_no = 0;
    $temp = 0;
    $ctoarray = array();

    $transaction = db_transaction(); //start database transaction
    try {
    /*
    * Prepare array structure to insert as a new or revised request
    * $flag = true - it is not importing, it is from home page browse button
    */
    $resultArray['requester_name'] = empty($sheetData[1]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[1]['B'];
    $resultArray['requester_email'] = empty($sheetData[2]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[2]['B'];
    $resultArray['request_number'] = empty($sheetData[3]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[3]['B'];
    $resultArray['customer_name'] = empty($sheetData[4]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[4]['B'];
    $resultArray['segment'] = empty($sheetData[5]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[5]['B'];
    $resultArray['dmu_cmr'] = empty($sheetData[6]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[6]['B'];
    $resultArray['cyborg_no'] = empty($sheetData[7]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[7]['B'];
    $resultArray['duty_type'] = empty($sheetData[8]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[8]['B'];
    $resultArray['country_code'] = empty($sheetData[9]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[9]['B'];
    $resultArray['billing_type'] = empty($sheetData[10]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[10]['B'];
    $resultArray['tier_1_partner'] = empty($sheetData[11]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[11]['B'];
    $resultArray['tier_2_partner'] = empty($sheetData[12]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[12]['B'];
    $resultArray['requested_tp'] = empty($sheetData[13]['B']) ? '' : (float)str_replace(',', '', $sheetData[13]['B']);
    $resultArray['deal_justification'] = empty($sheetData[14]['B']) ? '' : $sheetData[14]['B'];

    $cto_counter = 0 ;
    $ctocounterarray = array();

    if (!empty($sheetData)) {
    foreach ($sheetData as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($resultArray)) {
            if ($value['B'] == 'Part Number*') {
                $start_part_no = $key;
            }
            if ($start_part_no != 0 && $key > $start_part_no && $value['B'] != '') {
                if (($value['A'] == 'CTO' || $value['A'] == 'Regular') && $temp == 0) {
                    if($value['A'] == 'CTO'){
                        $part_no[] = array($value['B'] => array($value['C'], 'primary-cto'));
                        $cto_counter++;
                        $ctocounterarray[] =  $value['B'];
                    }else{
                        $part_no[] = array($value['B'] => array($value['C'], 'primary'));
                    }
                }
                if ($value['A'] == 'Bundle-Base' && trim($value['B']) != "" && !empty($value['B'])) {
                    $temp = 1;
                    $new_part_number = $value['B'];
                }
                if ($temp) {
                    if($value['A'] == "Bundle-Remove"){
                     $value['C'] = -1 * abs($value['C']);
                    }
                    $part_no[] = array($value['B'] => array($value['C'], $value['A']));

                    $ctoarray[$new_part_number][] = array($value['B'] => array($value['C'], $value['A']));
                }
                if ($value['A'] == 'CTO' && $temp == 1 && in_array($value['B'], $ctocounterarray)) {
                    $temp = 0;
                    $cto_counter--;
                }
            }
            $resultArray['part_no'] = $part_no;


        }
    }
    }

    $continue_flag = true;
    if($cto_counter !== 0){
    $transaction->rollback();
    drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' import failed' . PHP_EOL), 'error');
    import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 0,$resultArray['requester_email'],$resultArray['requester_name']);
    $continue_flag = false;
    $mail_id = ($flag) ? 0 : strstr($list->filename, '-', true); //split email id

    }

    $newRequest = '';
    $quotationSummary = '';
    $quotationLineItems = array();
    $mail_id = ($flag) ? 0 : strstr($list->filename, '-', true); //split email id
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //insert current date time in database
    $email_date = (isset($emailDates) && isset($emailDates[$mail_id]) && array_key_exists($mail_id, $emailDates)) ? date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($emailDates[$mail_id])) : $date;



    if (!$flag) {
    $result = db_select('quotation_request', 'qr')->fields('qr', array('email_number'))->condition('email_number', $mail_id, '=')->execute()->fetchAssoc();

    if (!empty($result)) {
        drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' already imported.' . PHP_EOL), 'warning');
        //import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 2);
        $continue_flag = false;
    }
    }

    $request_type = 'new';
    if ($continue_flag && !empty($resultArray)) {
    $request_number = '';
    if (empty($resultArray['request_number'])) {
        $request_number = import_sales_request_number(); //if the request is new
    } else {
        $revision = '';
        $revise_request_number = array(trim($resultArray['request_number']),trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R1',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R2',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R3',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R4',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R5',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R6',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R7',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R8',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R19',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R10',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R11',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R12',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R13',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R14',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R15',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R16',trim($resultArray['request_number']).'_R17');


        $result = db_select('quotation_request', 'qr')->fields('qr', array('request_number'))->condition('request_number',$revise_request_number , 'IN')->execute();

        $revision = $result->rowCount();
        if (!empty($revision) && $revision > 0) {
            $request_number = $resultArray['request_number'] . '_R' . $revision;
            $request_type = 'revise';
        } else {
            drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' has invalid request number.' . PHP_EOL), 'warning');
            import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 3,$resultArray['requester_email'],$resultArray['requester_name']);
            $continue_flag = false;


        }
    }

    /*
     * If all OK then it will create a new or revised request in database
     */
    if ($continue_flag) {
        /*
         * $newRequest - will have inserted request number
         */


        try {
            $newRequest = db_insert('quotation_request')->fields(array('email_number' => $mail_id, 'request_number' => $request_number,'request_type'=>$request_type, 'requester_name' => $resultArray['requester_name'], 'requester_email' => $resultArray['requester_email'], 'customer_name' => $resultArray['customer_name'], 'duty_type' => $resultArray['duty_type'], 'billing_type' => $resultArray['billing_type'], 'segment' => $resultArray['segment'],'request_file' => $list->filename, 'request_date_time' => $email_date, 'dmu_cmr' => $resultArray['dmu_cmr'], 'cyborg_no' => $resultArray['cyborg_no'], 'country_code' => $resultArray['country_code'], 'tier_1_partner' => $resultArray['tier_1_partner'], 'tier_2_partner' => $resultArray['tier_2_partner'], 'requested_tp' => $resultArray['requested_tp'], 'deal_justification' => $resultArray['deal_justification'], 'status' => 'generate quotation', 'created' => $date, 'uid' => $user->uid))->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            drupal_set_message(t('Error: %message', array('%message' => $e->getMessage())), 'error');

        }
        if (!empty($newRequest)) {
            try {
                $quotationSummary = db_insert('quotation_summary')->fields(array('quotation_request_id' => $newRequest, 'created' => $date, 'uid' => $user->uid))->execute();


            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                drupal_set_message(t('Error: %message', array('%message' => $e->getMessage())), 'error');
            }

            if (!empty($quotationSummary) && !empty($resultArray['part_no'])) {
                $base_part_no_id = 0;
                foreach ($resultArray['part_no'] as $key => $value) {
                    $part_no = key($value);
                    $quantity = (isset($value[$part_no][0])) ? $value[$part_no][0] : 0;
                    $part_no_behaviour = (isset($value[$part_no][1])) ? $value[$part_no][1] : 'primary';


                    $query = db_select('cost_tape', 'ct')->fields('ct', array('cost_tape_id'))->fields('ctp', array('bmc_price'))->condition('ct.part_number', $part_no);
                    $query->leftJoin('cost_tape_price', 'ctp', 'ct.cost_tape_id=ctp.cost_tape_id');
                    $query->orderBy('ctp.created', 'DESC')->range(0, 1);
                    $resultArrayAssoc = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

                    if (count($resultArrayAssoc) > 0) {
                        foreach ($resultArrayAssoc as $node) {
                            $cost_tape_id = $node->cost_tape_id;
                            $bmc_price = $node->bmc_price;
                            $not_found_part_number = "";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $not_found_part_number = $part_no;
                        $cost_tape_id = null;
                        $bmc_price = 0.0;
                    }

                    if($part_no_behaviour == 'CTO' || $part_no_behaviour == 'primary-cto'){
                        $not_found_part_number = $part_no;
                        $not_found_part_desc = "Server";
                        $cost_tape_id = null;
                    }else{
                        $not_found_part_desc = "";
                    }

                    try {
                        $quotationLineItem = db_insert('quotation_lineitems')->fields(array('quotation_request_id' => $newRequest, 'quotation_summary_id' => $quotationSummary, 'cost_tape_id' => $cost_tape_id, 'not_found_part_no' => $not_found_part_number, 'not_found_desc' => $not_found_part_desc, 'part_behavior' => $part_no_behaviour, 'ref_id' => $base_part_no_id, 'bmc_price' => $bmc_price, 'qty' => $quantity, 'created' => $date, 'uid' => $user->uid))->execute();

                            $quotationLineItems[] = $quotationLineItem;

                        if ($part_no_behaviour == 'Bundle-Base' && isset($quotationLineItem)) {
                            $base_part_no_id = $quotationLineItem;
                           // $quotationLineItems[] = $quotationLineItem;
                            $num_updated = db_update('quotation_lineitems') // Table name no longer needs {}
                                    ->fields(array('ref_id' => $base_part_no_id))
                                    ->condition('quotation_lineitems_id', $base_part_no_id, '=')
                                    ->execute();
                        }
                        if ($part_no_behaviour == 'CTO' && $base_part_no_id != 0) {
                            $base_part_no_id = 0;
                        }



                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        drupal_set_message(t('Error: %message', array('%message' => $e->getMessage())), 'error');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    if ($continue_flag && $newRequest && $quotationSummary && !empty($quotationLineItems)) {
    drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL));
    import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 1);

    $requester_name = $resultArray['requester_name'];
    $requester_email_id = $resultArray['requester_email'];

    $params = array(
        'subject' => "Price quote request has been received successfully. Customer Name :- ".$resultArray['customer_name']. " Request No :- ".$request_number,
        'body' => "<p>Hi ".$requester_name.",<br/></p>
                <p>Thanks for your email. DCG Pricing team will work on your price quote request and will shortly share the quotation with you.</p>
                <p>Your request number is ".$request_number.".</p>
                <p>Customer Name : ".$resultArray['customer_name'].".</p>
                <p>
            <strong>Attachment:&nbsp;</strong><a href='" . $base_url . "/sites/all/modules/pricecal/tmp/" . $list->filename . "'>Click here</a><br/>
    </p>
                <p>The dcgpricing@lenovo.com mailbox is dedicated to handle only price quote requests. For any other queries, please reach out to respective pricers.</p>
                <p>*** This is a system generated email, please do not reply to this email ***</p>
                <p>Thanks,<p/><p>DCG Pricing Team</p>",
    );
    drupal_mail('pricecal', 'success_sales_request', $resultArray['requester_email'], language_default(), $params);

    $customer_name = $resultArray['customer_name'];

    $params = array(
        'subject' => "New price quote request received",
        'body' => "<p>Hi Team,<br/></p>
                <p>The DCG pricing tool has successfully uploaded a price quote input request and is now available for your working.</p>
                <ul>
                <li>Request Number : ".$request_number."</li>
                <li>Customer name : ".$customer_name."</li>
                <li>Requestor name : ".$requester_name."</li>
                <li>Requestor email id : ".$requester_email_id."</li>
                <li>Deal justification : ".$resultArray['deal_justification']."</li>
                </ul>
                <p>
            <strong>Attachment:&nbsp;</strong><a href='" . $base_url . "/sites/all/modules/pricecal/tmp/" . $list->filename . "'>Click here</a><br/>
    </p>

                <p>*** This is a system generated email, please do not reply to this email ***</p>
                <p>Thanks,<p/><p>DCG Pricing Team</p>",
    );


    //drupal_mail('pricecal', 'import_success_email', 'chintan.p@blueoceanmi.com', language_default(), $params);

    } else if ($continue_flag) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    //drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' import failed' . PHP_EOL), 'error');
    import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 0, $resultArray['requester_email'],$resultArray['requester_name']);
    }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    drupal_set_message(t($list->filename . ' import failed' . PHP_EOL), 'error');
    import_sales_request_logfile($list->filename, 0, $resultArray['requester_email'],$resultArray['requester_name']);

    }
    rename($list->uri, drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . '/tmp/' . $list->filename);
    }
    } else {
    drupal_set_message(t('No email founds.' . PHP_EOL), 'warning'); //if no email found with unread status
    }
    return true;
    }

    /*
    * Create new request number and check weather request number already exists
    */

    function import_sales_request_number($length = 6) {
    $selectPartId = db_query("select count(request_number) as request_number from quotation_request")->fetchAssoc();

    if(empty($selectPartId['request_number'])){
    $token = 101;
    }else{
    $token = $selectPartId['request_number'] + 101;
    }
    return $token;
    }


    function import_sales_request_logfile($filename = '', $update = 0,$requester_emailId = '',$requesterName = '') {
    global $base_url;
    $log_file_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'pricecal') . '/logs/' . date('Y-M-d') . '.dat';

    $msg = ($update) ? $filename . ' imported success' . PHP_EOL : $filename . ' import failed' . PHP_EOL;

    if ($update == 0) {
    $msg = $filename . ' import failed' . PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($update == 1) {
    $msg = $filename . ' imported success' . PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($update == 2) {
    $msg = $filename . ' already imported' . PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($update == 3) {
    $msg = $filename . ' invalid request number' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents($log_file_path, date('h:i:sa ') . $msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    if(empty($requesterName)){
    $requesterName =  "Team";
    }

    if (in_array($update, array(0, 2, 3))) {
    $mail_id = strstr($filename, '-', true);
    $params = array(
    'subject' => $msg,
    'body' => "<p>Hi ".$requesterName.",<br/></p>
    <p>The DCG pricing tool has failed to upload a price quote input request(attached here) . Request you to please review and correct the template.
    </p>
    <p>
            <strong>Attachment:&nbsp;</strong><a href='" . $base_url . "/sites/all/modules/pricecal/tmp/" . $filename . "'>Click here</a><br/>
    </p>
    <p>*** This is a system generated email, please do not reply to this email ***</p>
    <p>Thanks,<br/>DCG Pricing Team</p>",
    );

    if(!empty($requester_emailId)){
    //drupal_mail('pricecal', 'import_success_email', 'chintan.p@blueoceanmi.com,'.$requester_emailId, language_default(), $params);    

    }else{
    // drupal_mail('pricecal', 'import_success_email', 'chintan.p@blueoceanmi.com', language_default(), $params);

    }

    }
    }


    function clean($string) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-@.]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    }
    ?>
```

I'm facing really serious issue on live server this code works fine 2 days before but now its saying memory exhausted, i tried to increase memory but still not working. Can you please somebody help me.

Comment: that's a lot of code, i dont have a spare hour

Comment: How big is your file your trying to upload/import, still looks like your trying to upload a huge file or something

Comment: 1) What webserver/hosting solution are you using, and is it local or not? 2) When you said that you "tried to increase memory," where exactly did you do that?  There are multiple places you can increase the memory for PHP AND Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for reply but issue was resolved, above code is okay to reading xls file and insert in to database. But it with scanning of directory and load all simultaneously so when i clean that directory than code run smoothly.